# Проверка логина в бд

Tags: база-данных, php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, где ошибся:

```
$login = 'admin';

$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admin_users` WHERE `login` = '$login' LIMIT 1",$db);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row[0] == ''){
echo 'нет!';
}

else{
echo 'да!';
}
```

---

Не мог добавить комментарий, добавил сюда.
andreyqin,

> echo 'SELECT id FROM ' . $prefix .
> '_users WHERE login = "' . $login .
> '"'; exit;

```
SELECT id FROM admin_users WHERE login = "admin"
```

запрос получается верный

Comment: Зачем в запросе используется ЛИМИТ? У вас много пользователей с одинаковыми логинами?

Почему вы решили что вы ошиблись?

Я бы использовал что-то в таким роде:

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    echo 'True';
} else {
    echo 'False';
}

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: @jackrv > Зачем в запросе используется ЛИМИТ?

чтобы движок не искал дальше первого совпадения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте как-то так:

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql');
mysql_select_db('db'); // тут укажите имя вашей базы данных
$login = 'admin';
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM admin_users WHERE login = "' . $login . '"');
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 'Логин занят';
} else {
    echo 'Логин свободен';
}
```

И откажитесь от использования mysql_ функций в пользу mysqli_ или PDO.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Ваш пример помог. Заметил, что еще не прописал, в какую бд добавлять
 
    .mysql_select_db('baza');

Стыдно, товарищи (((  
Недостаточно очков уважения для выполнения действия голос за.

Comment: @dafa, если ответ вам помог, вы можете пометить его как решение, нажав галочку рядом.

Comment: Подскажите еще немного. Допустим, необходимо, чтобы префикс FROM admin_users WHERE таблицы подставлялся из того же $login. Например:    
если `$login = 'admin'`,то `FROM admin_users WHERE`    
если `$login = 'user'`, то `FROM user_users WHERE`  
Это получается `('SELECT id FROM ' . $login . '_users WHERE login = "' . $login . '"');` 
но он выдает `"mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"`
Получается, не может получить заранее параметр? Если просто без переменной прописываю `FROM user_users WHERE`, то без ошибки.

Comment: По идее должно работать. Приведите полный кусок кода, как вы делаете.

Comment: Кусок кода:
   
    $login = $_POST['login'];   
    $prefix = $login;  
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql', 'mysql');
    mysql_select_db('baza');
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM ' . $prefix . '_users WHERE login = "' . $login . '"');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<div class="err">Логин занят</div>';
    } 

   
    <input type="text" name="login" value="">

В поле ввожу логин. Должна идти проверка на наличие логина в бд в таблице с префиксом, имеющим значение логина.

Comment: Во-первых, зачем городить лишние переменные? Почему бы в качестве префикса не использовать $login?
Во-вторых, посмотрите, что у вас приходит в $_POST['login'].

В-третьих, экранируйте пришедшие от пользователя данные. Почитайте, что такое SQL-иньекция и как обезопасить себя от неё.

Comment: Да, но даже если использую для префикса $login, то ошибка также.   
С $_POST['login'] все нормально, данные получает те, которые ввожу.  
Ошибка выводится, именно когда в качестве префикса ставлю переменную((

Comment: Магия. Проверьте, какой запрос вы в итоге получаете. Перед выполнением напишите:

echo SELECT id FROM ' . $prefix . '_users WHERE login = "' . $login . '"';
    exit;

Comment: А у тебя таблиц столько же, сколько логинов? Я что-то не пойму этой фичи...

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так :

```
function db_connect()
    {
        $host = "localhost"; //host
        $user = "root";  // Пользователь
        $pswd = "1234";  //password
        $db = "mega";    // Имя базы данных

        $connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");  // Делаем норм.восприятие русского языка
        if(!$connection || !mysql_select_db($db, $connection))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return $connection;  //   Подключаемся.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Я для этого использую COUNT()

```
$clusers = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM admin_users WHERE login='admin'"));

echo $clusers[0]." = Кол-во пользователей";

if ($clusers[0] == '0') {
echo "Такого пользователя нет";
} else {
echo "Пользователь есть";
}
```